# Measure-Command in windows .bat script: command not found

Tags: windows, powershell, time, measurement

I'm trying to write a script for measure execution time of a program.

If I type the command `Measure-Command` directly on PowerShell it work.

If I include that command in a script, then PowerShell tell me "command not found".

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.bat` scripts are not executed by `powershell.exe` but by `cmd.exe`. Since `Measure-Command` is a PowerShell cmdlet, cmd.exe won't recognise it.

You can call PowerShell from a `.bat` script if you like:

```
powershell -command "Measure-Command {Do-Something -Param1 stuff}|Select -Exp TotalSeconds" >> timing.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! :) So i have to write a cmdlet and include the command "Measure-Command"?